# Couldn't resolve flutter firestore in android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-plugin

I am using Android Studio 3.5 stable

java -version  1.8

and this is the issue :

**I have project gradle like this :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App gradle  like this :**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.takefun.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**& Pubspec.yaml  like this :**

```
name: Name
description: Expense.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+17
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.6
  fimber: ^0.3.2
  gradient_widgets: ^0.5.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.13.1
  flutter_vector_icons: ^0.2.0
  image_cropper: ^1.0.2
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.5
  stack_trace: ^1.9.3


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

**My iOS builds runs well but my android build is failing with console output :**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.database.firebase:database.firebase-firestore:19.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :cloud_firestore
   > Could not find com.google.database.firebase:database.firebase-core:16.0.9.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :firebase_core

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Flutter doctor has the following output (just listed android and android studio related ones):**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G87, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at /Users/adventure/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (5 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/adventure/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 38.2.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 37.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
```

I have also posted this issue to github here [firebaseExtended](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/17).
The reason to post it here too is due to the hope of people who respond to stackoverflow questions only as questions here are more discoverable than github if we haven't watched a particular repo.